# Alexa Skill needs more than 8s for a Lambda to complete

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using Alexa's Python libraries to write a Lambda that hits a couple of APIs. Sometimes, this takes more than 8s. That's when Alexa is set to timeout.

```py
class CustomIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("CustomIntentHandler")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        f = open('secrets.json')
        secrets = json.load(f)
        f.close
        
        # bulk of the code omitted (it works, it just takes too long sometimes)

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .response
        )
```

While I have found a specification in the API to help with this matter by deferring the response, I haven't been able to find any code samples that apply specifically to the Python libraries written for this. Where can I find such code samples to defer the response?

Answer (score 0):

Progressive responses are a good option in this case where you need to keep the user engaged while your skill prepares a full response to the user's request.

If you are interest in this option, please find more information on this link https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/send-the-user-a-progressive-response.html

This is a good example:
https://github.com/alexa-samples/progressive-response-demo